# Postgres data encryption for INT column

Tags: sql, postgresql, encryption, postgresql-9.1, rdbms

Say I have table:

`Fee
  date : DATE
  amount : INT`

I can't store data in `amount` column in virgin way, because this is private information, so I need to encrypt it. Also I need to perform arithmetic operations on that encrypted column, like:
`SELECT SUM(amount) FROM Fee;`

What is the best way to do that? Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption

Comment: http://crypto.cs.virginia.edu/courses/14s-pet/cryptdb-an-overview-and-why-it-belongs-in-the-private-social-network-encryption-system/

Comment: Konstantin, thank you. So I think I need to perform homomorpic encryption on client, but I can't find any implementation of homomorpic encryption algorythm for SUM operation.

Comment: You could try to ask at http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is the subject of lots of cryptography research, but in general is *very difficult*. The more common solution is to do the equivalent of `select sum( decrypt_int(amount, 'thekeydata') ) from ...`, i.e. you must know the key to perform operations like a sum.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Postgres's built-in column-level security?

Code:

```
create table employees (
    id int primary key,
    name text not null,
    salary decimal(10,2) not null 
);

insert into employees values (1, 'Frank', 60000.00);

create or replace view employees_view as 
    select
        id,
        name,
        case when has_column_privilege('employees', 'salary', 'select') then salary else null end as salary
    from employees;

create role managers;
create role clerks;

grant select on employees_view to managers;
grant select on employees_view to clerks;

grant select (salary) on employees to managers;

set role managers;
select * from employees_view;
```

Result: 1, 'Frank', 60000.00

```
set role clerks;
select * from employees_view;
```

Result: 1, 'Frank', null